# Creating a new column based off repeating rows

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to create a new column that includes the total repetitions per date.

**Before**

```
     date
0  6/1/18
1  6/1/18
2  6/4/18
3  6/5/18
4  6/6/18
6  6/6/18
7  6/6/18
```

**After**

```
     date  count
0  6/1/18    2
1  6/1/18    2
2  6/4/18    1
3  6/5/18    1
4  6/6/18    3
6  6/6/18    3
7  6/6/18    3
```

I tried using some similar solutions on this site to fit my criteria to no luck.

```
# Possible format I can use, but not what I am looking for.
df.loc[df['date'] == 1, 'b'].sum()
# I changed it to this to this to no solution.
df['Count'] = df.loc[df['date'] == df['date']].sum()
```

Perhaps I am on the wrong path, but any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: _to no solution._ What does that mean? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic]. _create a new column that includes the total repetitions per date_ Why keep that same format, then, instead of just the unique dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do

```
df['count']=df.date.groupby(df.date).transform('count')
df
     date  count
0  6/1/18      2
1  6/1/18      2
2  6/4/18      1
3  6/5/18      1
4  6/6/18      3
6  6/6/18      3
7  6/6/18      3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get rid of the duplicates, but keep the count...

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['6/1/18', '6/1/18', '6/4/18', '6/5/18', '6/6/18', '6/6/18','6/6/18']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': data})
df = df.pivot_table(columns=['Date'], aggfunc='size').reset_index()
df.rename(columns={0: 'Count'})

     Date  Count
0  6/1/18      2
1  6/4/18      1
2  6/5/18      1
3  6/6/18      3
```

Comment: ur answer doesnt seem to match what the OP wants

Comment: the OPs "after" sample didn't make sense to me, this does.